# Animate multiple images in iphone with CA

Tags: iphone, core-animation

i have a UIViewController which contains the 16 UIImageView now i have to annimate 4 images with Core Animation

any idea how to do this ?

i am able to animate the one only following is my code

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
anim.duration   = 1.5f;
anim.repeatCount =1;
anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
anim.autoreverses = YES;
anim.repeatCount = 10;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction        
functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[imgview.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing the same with the other image-views?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a theory solution in my mind, that in a loop from (1 to [yourImageArray count]) do load an imageView dynamically, load single image from yourImage array using index from that loop. Perform some animation using code on imageView.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageViews are subclasses of UIView, which have the following method:

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[imgview1 setCenter:CGPointMake(200,200)];
[imgview2 setCenter:CGPointMake(300,200)];
[imgview3 setCenter:CGPointMake(400,200)];
[imgview4 setCenter:CGPointMake(500,200)];
};
                     completion:nil];
```